# Copying Data in Excel

Tags: excel, database, copy-data

How can I copy data in Excel, if I have 3000 value and I want to copy data from 100 to 1000 only without dragging?

I tried the dragging option, but it takes a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

You can use goto (Keyboard shortcut is `Ctrl+g`), and enter a Range, e.g. `A100:E1000` which "goes to" and selects that range.

[image: Excel GoTo]

To be honest, dragging ain't the worst for only 900 rows :). Also there are keyboard shortcuts to select with navigation ... so for example, you can hold the shift key while you use the page up and page down keys, as well as arrow keys. You can also use filtering, in certain situations. If your desired range stands by itself, a handy shortcut is `ctrl+shift+spacebar` to select an entire contiguous range all at once.